# Can't use vue-router and pinia inside a single store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, pinia

I am using pinia and vue-router 4.x ,but i am having a problem using both of them in a store.
each works independently ,but not together.

If i use

```
import router from '../router'
```

router will work but pinia is failed with  error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'useAuthStore' before initialization
at axiosroot.ts

@line let authStore = useAuthStore(pinia);
```

//here is axiosroot.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import {useAuthStore} from '../stores/auth-store'
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
 const pinia=createPinia();
let authStore = useAuthStore(pinia);
const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api";
const   myToken =authStore.getToken;
export default axios.create({
  url,
  headers:{"Accept":"application/json"},
  
});
```

When i import router from vue-routern `useRouter` is undefined

```
import {useRouter} from 'vue-router'
const router =useRouter();
```

the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') 
--- 
error @ line router.push({name:'Login'})
```

// here is the remainning  relavant code

```
import { defineStore, acceptHMRUpdate } from "pinia";
//import router from '../router'
import {useRouter} from 'vue-router'
const router =useRouter();
export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
 id: "user",
 actions: {  
   LogOut(payload) {
     // this.DELETE_TOKEN(null);
     // this.UPDATE_LOGIN_STATUS(false);
     router.push({name:'Login'})
   },
 },
});
```

Answer (score 32):

Router has to be used as a plugin in pinia. I read this in the pinia.documentation https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html

> When adding external properties, class instances that come from other libraries, or simply things that are not reactive, you should wrap the object with markRaw() before passing it to pinia. Here is an example adding the router to every store:

```js
import { markRaw } from 'vue'
// adapt this based on where your router is
import { router } from './router'

pinia.use(({ store }) => {
  store.router = markRaw(router)
})
```

This will add pinia to every store you create. The config in main.ts is the same as for vue plugins.

```js
import { createApp, markRaw } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import App from './app/App.vue';
import { router } from './modules/router/router';

const app = createApp(App);
const pinia = createPinia();

pinia.use(({ store }) => {
  store.$router = markRaw(router)
});
app.use(router)
```

Now you can access router in your stores.

```js
export const useMyStore = defineStore("myStore", {
  state: () => {
    return {};
  },
  actions: {
    myAction() {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' }); 
  },
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to add/extend Pinia types to accommodate this new property to the store?

Comment: app.use(pinia) is missing otherwise you'll get: Uncaught Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
 const pinia = createPinia()
 app.use(pinia)

Comment: How do you access such properties when using a setup store though? Where there is no `this`?

Comment: Thanks for this. I spent several hours trying to figure out why I couldn't call useStore() in a pinia action method. This solved it. It's not exactly intuitive but what about Vuejs really is

Comment: I had to replace the line

    **store.$router = markRaw(router)**

with 

   **store.store.$router = markRaw(router)**

to correctly inject $router into the store's state. I'm using Vue 2.

Answer (score 8):

In **main.js**:

```
import { createApp, markRaw } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const pinia = createPinia()
pinia.use(({ store }) => {
store.router = markRaw(router)
})
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)
app.use(router) 
app.mount('#app')
```

In your store push routes with:

```
this.router.push({ name: 'home' });
```

Comment: i did the same but it doesnt work

Answer (score 5):

I resolved that wrapping the store in a function:

```
/*** THIS DOES NOT WORK ****/
const router = useRouter();

export const useLoginStore = defineStore("login", {
  state: () => ({
    loading: false,
    error: "",
  }),
  actions: {
    loginAction(credentials: AuthenticationRequest): Promise<void> {
      await login(credentials);
      router.replace("/")
    },
  },
});



/*** This actually works ***/
export default function useLoginStore() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return defineStore("login", {
    state: () => ({
      loading: false,
      error: "",
    }),
    actions: {
      loginAction(credentials: AuthenticationRequest): Promise<void> {
        await login(credentials);
        router.replace("/")
      },
    },
  })();
}
```

Comment: doest work for me

Comment: After working more on pinia, it is better to use pinia plugin as explained [here](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html)

Comment: useLoginStore is supposed to cache the result, while it returns a new store every time.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using quasar v2. This worked for me

in your /src/stores/index.js file, add the following

```
import { markRaw } from 'vue'
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers'

pinia.use(({ store }) => {
  // important! dont add a $router here
  store.router = markRaw(route)
})
```

Then in your src/stores/[yourStore].js file use

```
this.router.push("/") // important! dont add a $router here
```

I was having trouble when trying to add the $router as suggested in the top answer

Comment: This is a good solution for quasar. But your answer has has an error. Your `markRaw(router)` shoud be `markRaw(route)`. Tested it and it worked

Comment: thnx for that. hv updated the answer.

Comment: In the Quasar documentation it is written that you may include your router into your Quasar app by adding it in `quasar.config.js` throught the option [sourceFiles](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#sourcefiles). Thereafter, you are able to [use the router from within your store](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/state-management-with-pinia#accessing-the-router-in-pinia-stores)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using quasar Framework v2

Locate /src/stores/index.js file and edit by

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router' ---> import this

// You can add Pinia plugins here
// pinia.use(SomePiniaPlugin)
pinia.router = useRouter() ---> add this line
```

in the Store file

```
this.router.push({ name: 'Home' }) --> use this
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use router in Pinia without passing methods, props or Object a cleaner solution could be this.

```
import './assets/main.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const pinia = createPinia()

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(pinia)
app.use(router)
app.provide('router', router);
app.mount('#app')
```

And then in your store:

```
import { inject } from "vue";
actions: {
    navigate() {
      const router = inject('router');
      router.push({
        name: "customers",
        params: { page: this.currentPage },
      });
    },
},
```

pinia.use() is more flexible and allows you to pass plugins, methods, Object, props.
Both are fine for the porpouse of passing router to pinia.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern which seems to work quite well.

After action initState() you'll have this.route & this.router available

This is for pinia, but would work just as well with vuex.

```js
// any store.js

export const useStore = defineStore('my-store') => {
  return state: () => {
    router: null,
    route: null
  },
  actions: {
    initState ({ router, route }) {
      this.router = router;
      this.route = route;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
// app.vue

<script setup>

const store = useStore();

const router = useRouter();

const route = useRoute();

store.initState({ router, route })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using quasar and resolve the error as follows.

```js
actions: {
    async login(email, password) {
     .....
      await this.api.post('auth/login/', data).then((response) => {
        this._p.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' });
      });
    },
```

Something you can do is console.log(this) and you will see everything that your instance contains, in my case it was in "_p".
I hope and serve you.

Answer (score -2):

It should work if you declare `const router = useRouter();` inside your store action instead of at the top of the module.

It's the same for `const store = useSomeStore()` declarations. They can't be used at the module route, and are often used within component `setup` functions and store actions.

You don't *need* to create a plugin, but if you're likely to be using the router across all your stores it still might be worth doing so as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70905178/3428475)

Comment: Did not work...

Comment: Yeah it won't work inside an action method either

Comment: Pinia kinda sucks