# How to get the current route name inside a pinia store?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, pinia, vue-router4

I'm creating an application that needs to query different collections for each view.

I believe that the simplest way to do this would be to assign the name of the route to a variable that corresponds to the name of the collection in the Firestore within my pinia store.

And then call that variable when querying the collection, like this.

```
async getNotes() {
     

      getNotesSnapshot = onSnapshot(collection(db, 'users', userId, thisRouteName)
, (querySnapshot) => {
        let notes = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let note = {
          id: doc.id,
          content: doc.data().content,
          date: doc.data().date
        }
        notes.push(note)

        })
        this.notes = notes
      })
    }
```

How do I assign the current route name in thisRouteName variable?

Comment: try the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70681667

Comment: Im still cannot get to return the current route name :/

Comment: I think the simplest way is to pass the route name as a parameter when calling pinia action from the route component.